# Problem with boldmath followed by super or subscript in tex4ebook

Tags: tex4ht, bugs, tex4ebook, mathml

The latex file

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbf{x}^y$
\end{document}
```

when compiled with

```
tex4ebook -f epub3 test "mathml"
```

produces the following mathml:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline" > 
<mstyle mathvariant="bold"><mi>x</mi><msup><mrow></mstyle></mrow><mrow><mi>y</mi></mrow></msup></math>
```

The open and close tags don't match, this is incorrect HTML, and resulting in the error:

```
 DOM parsing of test.xhtml failed
```

A similar error happens with `$\mathbf{x}'$` (which is really a superscript), and also with subscripts.

A simple fix for these is to enclose the expression before the super or subscript, as in

```
${\mathbf{x}}^y$
${\mathbf{x}}'$
${\mathbf{x}}_0$
```

but the original expression should work because it is legitimate LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

TeX4ht unfortunately cannot support sub- and superscripts without proper grouping. Only thing you can try is to pre-process your input file and add grouping. For example, using the following Lua file:

```lua
for line in io.lines() do
  -- regex that reads command that contains just text
  local command= "(\\.-{[^{]-})"
  line = line:gsub(command .. "%^", "{%1}^") -- fix \mathrm{a}^...
  line = line:gsub("%^"..command, "^{%1}") -- fix ...^\mathrm{a}
  line = line:gsub(command .. "_", "{%1}_") -- fix \mathrm{a}_...
  line = line:gsub("_"..command, "_{%1}") -- fix ..._\mathrm{a}
  line = line:gsub(command .. "'", "{%1}'") -- fix \mathrm{a}'...
  print(line)
end
```

This scripts reads standard input and outputs modified code. For example, it replaces the following input:

```
$\mathbf{x}^y$
$\mathbf{x}'$
$\mathbf{x}^\mathbf{y}$
$\mathbf{x}_\mathbf{y}$
```

with this output:

```
${\mathbf{x}}^y$
${\mathbf{x}}'$
${\mathbf{x}}^{\mathbf{y}}$
${\mathbf{x}}_{\mathbf{y}}$
```

You can execute it with `tex4ebook` using:

```
texlua fix_scripts.lua < test.tex | tex4ebook -f epub3 -j test - "mathml"
```

This is the result:

[image]